# MYSQL Search by arrays

Tags: mysql, arrays

Got a question for you all...

What would be the best way to search my table by array, that has an array in the table.

EG:

```
$var = (1,4,7,9,14)

$Query = "SELECT * FROM business_listings WHERE category IN ($var)";
```

`'category'` would have `4,27,89,101`

How can I get this to match if one of the numbers in the `$var` matches one of the numbers in the table.

Comment: Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: With php arrays I believe you need to use the join() method using commas as delimeters

Comment: Sounds like you have an problem with denormalization and you should normalize...

Answer (score 0):

If your database column is a list of comma separated values, and you're searching for one value in that list, then you're in a different situation.

If your `category` column contains the text value `410,406,149,152`, like you commented below, and you're searching for fields whose `category` contains `152`, then you'll need to use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

If you have to check multiple values, then you need to use more than one `FIND_IN_SET`. If you read the documentation, you'll see that the first argument for `FIND_IN_SET` must be a single string, not a string list (it can't contain a comma). Use the following instead:

```
$var = "401,320,152";
$items = explode(",", $var);
foreach ($items as &$i) {
    $i = "FIND_IN_SET('" . $i . "', `category`)";
}
$search = implode(" OR ", $items);
unset($i);
$query = "SELECT * FROM business_listings WHERE " . $items;
```

This will output:

```
SELECT * FROM business_listings WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('401', `category`) OR
    FIND_IN_SET('320', `category`) OR
    FIND_IN_SET('152', `category`)
```

The above script will work even if `$var` contains only one value.

Finally, as **tadman** mentioned, since we're getting into queries that can be tricky to build with prepared statements, you need to make sure you're [escaping and sanitizing your input properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129677/). For an example, if `$var` is being retrieved from the user somehow, then before you modify it in any way, you need to escape it with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$var = $mysqli->real_escape_string($var);
```

Assuming that `$mysqli` is your open MySQLi connection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so my $var now reads '152'
my table reads 410,406,149,152

but it only works if the 152 is the first number.  It looks like its only looking at the first number in the table, not the others

if $var = 410 it works
if $var = 152 it doesn't work

Comment: Ah! I guess I misunderstood what you're trying to do. See my edit.

Comment: If you're going to compose a query using string concatenation, please **properly escape** anything going in there. This is a bad pattern to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the help theftprevention
so if my $var ="401,152" it doesn't work

Comment: Everything seems to be working great, until I add LIMIT 10,0

if I add that I don't get anything.
It seems like the OFFSET is causing the problem as LIMIT 10 works fine

Comment: Well, look at the [**`LIMIT` clause**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm46914929224272). When there's only one argument (i.e. `LIMIT 10`), the argument is interpreted as a `length`. You'll get 10 results, at most. But when there are two arguments, then the first is an `offset` and **the second is a `length`.** So, `LIMIT 10,0` tells MySQL to start at the eleventh row (because `offset` counts from 0), and to return a maximum of *zero rows.* So, it seems you got your arguments swapped.